# How to find out who shared a page on Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

One of my blog posts has two +1's on it's social button (Google Plus). I wonder who liked my page. How to find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out with Google Analytics "Network Referrals". It includes "Social User Handle
" and "User Profile URL".

Comment: If you can give the same answer to two different questions it's an indication they're duplicates. In that case please flag one of the questions as a possible duplicate of the other rather than answering.